# An example of a non-regular grammar for a regular language?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, formal-grammars

I understand that a regular language can be specified by either regular or non-regular grammars.  What is an example of a non-regular grammar for a regular language?

Comment: Is it worthwhile to add an example to the Wikipedia article?

Comment: I'll offer that as an extra credit opportunity to my students.  :-)

Comment: hey how can we tell that if the grammar is regular or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular Language L = {aab}

Non-regular grammar

S -> aAb

A -> a

Comment: hey how can we tell that if the grammar is regular or not?

Comment: I want to modify the question: Is there a regular language having "infinite strings" which can be generated by a non regular grammar?